# Will copy and pasting the SDK folder from one PC to another PC works in Android Studio?

Tags: sdk, android-studio

I have two computers(say PC1 and PC2).

1. I had downloaded android studio and installed in both of the computers.
2. In both computers sdk is located in  **C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk**.
3. Now using sdk manager i'll update(i'll install some packages)  SDK present in PC1.
4. Now If i replace the sdk folder present in PC2 with the new updated SDK folder present in PC1, will it work ? Can i use new features that i installed in PC1 in PC2 also;  or,  do i need to update SDK seperately in both PC's

Comment: from point 1 to 3, why don't try it and tell us what happened, and on point 4 i guess the features after the copy/paste should stay but future updates on PC1, obviously... not

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. Copying SDK from one PC to another PC works. I copied updated SDK present in PC1 to PC2 and i got all the new features in PC2 also. It works.

Comment: To reiterate what Scott said... assuming same OS on both PCs.

Comment: even the emulator?

Answer (score 6):

You can copy SDKs from computer to computer; the SDK update process doesn't make any changes outside of the SDK folder itself, and it doesn't hardcode any paths into the SDK installation. This works as long as the machine you're copying to is the same OS; trying to copy an SDK from a Linux installation to Windows, for example, would cause problems.

Comment: is sdk from win 7 will be ok to put in win 8.1?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can copy the folder to another PC as such.
But if you want to copy paste the whole Android Studio to another PC you need to copy SDK, installer, `.gradle` folder, `.android` folder.

`.android` and `.gradle` folder is in

```
C:\Users\*Username*\
```

and as for the SDK, you need to copy folder Android Present in the following location

```
C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) You can use %HOMEPATH% on Windows as a shortcut to the user's folder.

Comment: That's very important.